# vb.net check if registry subkey value exists

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have an winform which saves registration data to the registry under "Ddoe" - however I need to check if the value has previously been set (created) in doing so I attempted to do:

```
If (Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\FCRA\Assignment").GetValue("Ddoe") Is Nothing Then
'doesnt exist
else
'exists
end if
```

however this is not functioning properly

I am receiving an error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in #appname
```

it is showing this error at the if statement line

is there a better way to check for the existence of this registry entry or am I going about this all wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\FCRA\Assignment" does not exist, so `OpenSubKey` returns `Nothing`. You cannot use any methods on a `Nothing` value. Try this one:

```
If My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\FCRA\Assignment",
                                 "Ddoe", Nothing) Is Nothing Then
  'value does not exist
End If
```

Taken from here:

- [How to: Determine if a Value Exists in a Registry Key in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ky500c4y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)